# Using the twitter bootstrap 3 basic navbar semantically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to know if there is a way to include the twitter bootstrap 3 basic navbar semantically using less and your own classes instead of using the prebuilt classes like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there any difference between the navbar of B3 and the navbar of B2?

Comment: @pigueiras, yes class names are changed, see http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/migrate-your-templates-from-twitter-bootstrap-2-x-to-twitter-bootstrap-3/

Comment: @gevvek your classe names are not defined in less. You can extend or change the css of the classes with less.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417478/is-it-possible-to-alias-a-class-or-tag-to-another-class-or-tag-in-sass-or-less

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can thru bootstrap's mixins

have a read on this article

http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html

Comment: Bootstrap does not expose mixin for navbar component